# Make UIView class conform UILayoutSupport protocol

Tags: ios, swift

For some reason I wish to use `UIView` instances as `UILayoutSupport`.

[`UILayoutSupport` protocol defenition](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILayoutSupport_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UILayoutSupport/length):

```
protocol UILayoutSupport: NSObjectProtocol {
    var length: CGFloat { get }                   //Required
    var bottomAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor { get } //Required
    var heightAnchor: NSLayoutDimension { get }   //Required
    var topAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor { get }    //Required
}
```

[UIView class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/) already conform to `NSObjectProtocol`, as well as already have same way declared properties `bottomAnchor`, `heightAnchor`, `topAnchor`. So, the question is: why with this extension

```
extension UIView: UILayoutSupport {
    var lenght: CGFloat {
        return bounds.size.height
    }
}
```

I still have error

> Type 'UIView' does not conform to protocol 'UILayoutSupport'

Comment: try setting the property as public?

Comment: @FedericoZanetello tried, same result

Comment: You have a typo anyway. Your length property in the protocol doesnt match the name of lenght in the extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you swapped the last two property letters: leng**ht** instead of leng**th**

Comment: What a stupid mistake. I was sure that I used copy- paste. Thank you!

Comment: Haha I do it all the time: it drives me crazy because all seems perfect but the compiler keeps complaing